# sqlite3.OperationalError: table quiz has no column named question (python 3.11)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Я писал программу при помощи sqlite3, но когда захотел вставить данные в таблицу, выдало ошибку: **sqlite3.OperationalError: table quiz has no column named question**

Нужный кусок кода:

```
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect(filename) as db:
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE quiz(
                 number_question INT UNSIGNED
                 question VARCHAR
                 variant1 VARCHAR
                 variant2 VARCHAR
                 variant3 VARCHAR
                 variant4 VARCHAR
                 answer VARCHAR
   );""")


   while number_question<=quantity_questions:
     cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO quiz(number_question, question, variant1, variant2, variant3, variant4, answer) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", [number_question, question[number_question-1], variant1[number_question-1], variant2[number_question-1], variant3[number_question-1], variant4[number_question-1], answer[number_question-1]])
   number_question+=1
   print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `table "quiz" has no column named "question"` — требуется перевод этой фразы?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Перевод понятен, но дело в том, что я создал колонку, а он пишет, что ее нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ты забыл запятые поставить ;)

```py
import sqlite3
with sqlite3.connect(filename) as db:
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE quiz(
                 number_question INT UNSIGNED,
                 question VARCHAR,
                 variant1 VARCHAR,
                 variant2 VARCHAR,
                 variant3 VARCHAR,
                 variant4 VARCHAR,
                 answer VARCHAR
   );""")


   while number_question<=quantity_questions:
     cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO quiz(number_question, question, variant1, variant2, variant3, variant4, answer) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", [number_question, question[number_question-1], variant1[number_question-1], variant2[number_question-1], variant3[number_question-1], variant4[number_question-1], answer[number_question-1]])
   number_question+=1
   print(cursor.fetchall())
```